# Pass an extra argument to paging extender

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to amend this paging extender: http://jsfiddle.net/zeelux/B4vN2/ to accept a `currentPage` variable rather than it be hard-coded.

`pageSize` is passed as an argument but I'm not familiar with the syntax how to add an additional argument.

e.g.

```
ko.extenders.paging = function(target, pageSize, currentPage) {
...
}
```

and

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([...]).extend({
        paging: 5, 2
    });
};
```

isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add multiple arguments to your extender function but you can pass in **an object** as the second argument of the extender, which contains the two config options:

```
ko.extenders.paging = function(target, config) {
    // default pageSize to 10
    var _pageSize = ko.observable(config.pageSize || 10),
    // default current page to 1
    _currentPage = ko.observable(config.currentPage || 1); 
   //...
}
```

Then you can pass in an object with the right properties when using the extender:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([...]).extend({
         paging: { pageSize: 5, currentPage : 2 }
    });
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gU6pt/).

Note: you can make the extender even smarter: based on the `config` parameter's type if it is an number use it as the `pagesize` etc.